# Python3 editing hex string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a file's hex size in the header of another file. When I convert the length to hex I get `b'\x00\x00\x00\x04'`  so it writes `"00000004"` to the file.

The file's length is stored in 2 byte intervals though, so I need it to format the string to this `b'\x00\x04'`. what the easiest way to do this?

```
import mmap
def compact_bytes(values):
    return (values[0] << 4)| values[2]
```

I tried this but I know it's not correct and not the proper method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting a number into bytes, not hex. Use the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to do this:

```
struct.pack('>H', values)
```

This produces an unsigned short, 2 bytes, in big endian order; for the length `4` that'd produce `\x00\x04`:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('>H', 4)
b'\x00\x04'
```

Comment: thats awesome, thanks so much^_^ and sorry i always say that "hex" when i mean "bytes" : /

Comment: was already using stuct.pack but was using the '>i' argument. the ">H" fixed it thanks, next time ill do some more reading on the struct documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the integer is an big endian unsigned short, use [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack) with the big endian flag.

```
struct.pack('>H', values)
```

In this format string, `>` is the big endian flag, and `H` is unsigned short.

### Example:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('>H', 4)
b'\x00\x04'
```

You can find all the `struct` format characters [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> 4 .to_bytes(2, 'big')
b'\x00\x04'
```